# How can I design the Ionic button with symbols on the right side?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, mobile, ionic2, hybrid

I am using a following simple ionic button with blue background and white label. But I need the one with oval-shaped and with the symbols at the right. I have attached both of the images (the button which I am using now & the button which I need actually). How can I design the button according to that, Since I am new to Ionic.

I have attached my coding and images:

My HTML snippet for currently using button:

```
<ion-item>
<div>
<button ion-button name="submitbutton" (click)="submitforget()" tabindex="3" #submitbutton class="submitbutton">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>
  </ion-item>
```

My CSS for current button:

```
.submitbutton{
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: right;

}
```

My Actual button:

[image: image of actual button:]

But I need the button as below:

[image: image of button actually needed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is default button widget in ionic.

Try below code

```
<button ion-button icon-end>
Right Icon
<ion-icon name="star"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

You can find more [Here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/button/Button/)

Comment: Welcome glad to help :)